# Visual Studio Code Linker - case insensitive switch?

Tags: visual-studio-code

An old Amiga assembly program I'm resurrecting in Visual Studio Code with Amiga Assembler extension (which uses FS-UAE as emulator), has many case insensitive label issues, giving me the following errors...

```
Linker error: Link Error 21(PlatformDesigner+0x1de8): Reference to undefined symbol setcondDelay
```

The label setcondDelay is seen in different case versions. Fixing one shows more and more of the same problem, and there's over 7000 lines of code.

**Is there a case insensitive switch in VS-Code in the linker** that will at least let me get the code running? It runs ok on a real Amiga 1200 (using Asm-One to assemble) and in WinUAE.

Comment: Hello, please add the correct context. As a suggestion, look into what assembler linker you are using: visual studio code is a text editor, so it is not the one responsible for running your code and the error you may get. Maybe it is some extension you are using?

Comment: I recommend looking into your assembler and figuring out whether or not there is a case sensitivity flag. Another option is to write code that finds all switch statements and does a to_lower (or similar) call on them to move them all lower case, if you are positive they are all meant to be case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks you. I've clarified the context (VS-Code with Amiga Assembly extension which uses FS-UAE as emulator). I'll check if FS-UAE has any accessible case settings. I should have enabled Asm One's case-sensitive switch all those years ago :(

Comment: VS Code is not a linker and VS Code is not the program giving you the linker error. Your linker is the one giving you the error. Look into the docs for your linker / assembler. Fix you quesiton title and tags.

Comment: Thanks for this, edited to focus on linker. Will look for FS-UAE/linker docs.